# g_hash_table_lookup() not accepting variable as parameter

Tags: c, casting, gtk

Consider the following code:

```
gtk_widget_show(g_hash_table_lookup(widgetbuffer,"togglebutton"));
gtk_toggle_button_set_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(g_hash_table_lookup(widgetbuffer,"togglebutton"))),TRUE);
```

Line one works fine, line two throws this error:

```
Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_toggle_button_set_active: assertion `GTK_IS_TOGGLE_BUTTON (toggle_button)' failed
```

Why is this? If g_hash_table_lookup is returning a GtkWidget pointer that gtk_widget_show handles just fine, why can't `GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON()` cast it's type properly?

(Also, gtk_toggle_button_set_active causes no errors on compile, only at runtime)

Edit: For clarity, it *is* a gtktogglebutton (Note the dereferencer and how it now causes an error):

```
gtk_toggle_button_set_active(*GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(g_hash_table_lookup(widgetbuffer,"togglebutton"))),TRUE);
note: expected ‘struct GtkToggleButton *’ but argument is of type ‘GtkToggleButton’
```

**However**

```
printf("Pointer: %p\n",GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(g_hash_table_lookup(widgetbuffer,(gchar *) xmlGetProp(cur2, (xmlChar *) "name"))));
printf("Xml data: %s\n",xmlGetProp(cur2, (xmlChar *) "name"));
printf("hash table output pointer: %p\n\n",g_hash_table_lookup(widgetbuffer,xmlGetProp(cur2, (xmlChar *) "name")));
```

Thoroughly confused.

Typical output:

```
Pointer: (nil)
Xml data: log
hash table output pointer: (nil)
```

Just to make sure:

```
printf("Manual hash table output pointer: %p\n", g_hash_table_lookup(widgetbuffer,(gchar *) "log"));
printf("Manual hash table output pointer: %p\n", g_hash_table_lookup(widgetbuffer,"log"));
printf("Manual hash table output pointer: %p\n", g_hash_table_lookup(widgetbuffer,"(char *) log"));
```

All return:

```
Manual hash table output pointer: 0x1e08430
```

Comment: Erm, it's telling you that the widget you're casting and passing in isn't actually a toggle button.

Comment: But is is. Or to be more precise, it's a GtkCheckButton (Which inherits from togglebutton) `gtk_toggle_button_set_active` worked fine if I passed it `GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(gtk_builder_get_object)` as opposed to storing it in a `GHashTable` and then passing it on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something has removed the last reference to your toggle button between the time when it was added to the hash table and when you call `set_active()` on it?

But I think it's more likely you're not getting the pointer out that you think you are. Your trick of dereferencing `*GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(g_hash_table_lookup(...))` doesn't tell you anything about the pointer stored in the hash table; `GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON()` casts any pointer to `GtkToggleButton *`, so no matter what you dereference, you will always get something that the compiler thinks is a `GtkToggleButton` structure.

Comment: I had an if statement inverted somewhere